# how to not match a pattern in xml

Tags: xml, perl, unix

Log collector takes path to collect the log files. How to omit the "undo" files present in path4 directory.
Collect logs from path below but omit undo files from path4

```
<logs>  
    <log path="/path1/path2/path3/^[undo]*"/>  
</logs>
```

/path1/path2/path3/path4/undo1.txt
/path1/path2/path3/path4/undo2.txt

Comment: Which log collector? This is important - XML handling is different from plain text handling.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the tags that this log collector takes a perl regular expression or something like it, then it'd be:

```
<logs>  
    <log path="/path1/path2/path3/(?!undo)[^/]*"/>  
</logs>
```

(Depending on whether the log collector needs the regular expression to match the whole file name, the `[^/]*` at the end may not be necessary)

Unfortunately, the name "log collector" is a bit generic, so I don't actually know what software you mean, so I don't know if it in fact does take a perl regular expression; it would be helpful to give a reference to the actual software your using.

---

Okay, here's what that that regular expression should match, using this perl test program:

```
my $re = qr{/path1/path2/path3/(?!undo)[^/]*};

for (<>) {
  chomp;
  if ($_ =~ $re) {
    print "$_ matches\n"
  } else {
    print "$_ DOES NOT MATCH\n"
  }
}
```

That shows us:

```
/path1/path2/path3/foo.txt matches
/path1/path2/path3/bar.log matches
/path1/path2/path3/undo_5.txt DOES NOT MATCH
/path1/path2/path3/ matches
```

This is why I really wanted a pointer to the software. Because you say that the revised regex does not work, that "undo" files are still getting pulled in, and that tells me that the log software does not match the full filename to the regular expression, but only the path (directory) name. We can see from the evidence above that the regular expression does not match files with names beginning with "undo".

And since you want some files in the directory to be matched and some not, you should hope that your software has something like a separate `file=` attribute that accepts a regular expression for the file names.

Comment: the log collector uses perl reg expression.

Comment: I would hope it doesn't, as you're reading `XML`, and regular expression processing of XML is nasty.

Comment: I tried with the changes, But the undo files still exist.

Comment: The files beginning with undo, which is under path4 are getting matched and is being collected every time.   The files and dir's under path3 needs to be logged .

Comment: @user3269606 That regular expression will not match files beginning with undo. Therefore, the log collector is not in fact matching files with that regular expression - is it maybe matching directories? (Since that expression will match `/path1/path2/path3/`) What if you change to `/path1/path2/path3/(?!undo)[^/]+` ?

Comment: @ikegami undo is a file under path4 not a directory. Like undo_fil1.txt and undo_fil2.txt.    but i am collecting log from path3 which needs to exclude the undo files which are under path4. excluding the undo files i need to collect all files and folders which come under path3.

Comment: @DanielMartin could you explain what the below expression does     /(?!undo)[^/]+  ?

Comment: Updated answer to show what the expression matches. If you need to understand how it works, any guide to perl regular expressions covering negative lookahead would work. (for example, http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)